aiogram 3.10 doesn't want to run my middleware
Wrote my first middleware to check if a user is logged in, the middleware doesn't want to work at all.
Python code:
   class CheckUserExist(BaseMiddleware):
async def __call__(
        self,
        handler: Callable[[Message, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
        event: Message,
        data: Dict[str, Any]
) -> Any:
    user = data['event_from_user']
    print(user)
    user_id = user.id
    print('Base')

    If not await check_user_exist(user_id):
        await event.answer('You are not registered. Please register using the /start command.")
    else:
        return await handler(event, data)

And I connect it this way
Python code:
router.message.middleware(user_check.CheckUserExist())
I am using aiogram 3.10, python 3.10 too
I've tried both with dispatcher and router, but either the bot goes on a binge and doesn't respond at all or nothing there but middleware.
